# Managing multiple servers with shared accounts and filesystem

Tags: server

At work we have about 7 servers, quite heterogeneous but all running AMD64 architectures, which we would like to join and manage from a single machine, preserving the fact that all of them can also be used as desktop computers.

The basic idea is to have all servers share configuration (i.e. installed software), accounts and one partition devoted to a shared filesystem.

Is this posible with Ubuntu? So far we have had to install Ubuntu and manage it on each individual computer, but it is a mess to keep up with upgrades and allow people access to different computers. Does Ubuntu and any of the tools it provides (MAAS, Juju, etc) help in any way here?

P.S.: We would like to stick to free software here. We cannot afford pay for maintenance and also this is a private network sitting behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You primary requirement need to set up an environment with a shared authentication database

But If you only need a nice management tool, install and try Webmin and give it a try.

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.680_all.deb
dpkg -i webmin_1.680_all.deb
apt-get -f install
```

Open interface by `https://yourserverIP:10000` and login

Comment: on webmin webpage there is repo for 12.04. I would recommend that way. Just let apt-get deal with updates.

Comment: @Fih Webmin will look for updates automatically without having to add the repository.